# Yocto recipe for adding export to .bash_profile

Tags: yocto, recipe, openembedded

how can I define environmental variables I would otherwise put in .bashrc or .bash_profile using export into a build of yocto, so as not to do it everytime I flash OS.

For particulars:
Board I am building for : Toradex Apalis T30
I am adding this recipe : https://github.com/bmwcarit/meta-ros

As shown in readme of the above recipe, we need to `set up the environment with`

```
export ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros
export ROS_DISTRO=indigo
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/indigo/share
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/ros/indigo/bin
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ros/indigo/lib
export PYTHONPATH=/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/site-packages
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/ros/indigo
touch /opt/ros/indigo/.catkin
```

Also how can I add the last touch to run only once.(I suppose it need not be ran every time a terminal is opened).

I tried to make a service to declare these variables, but I think that's not the most efficient(or atleast good) method of doing the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there's a simpler way but I created a .bbappend of the "base-files" recipe provinding the `.profile` file with

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
```

inside.

Then in you need to have a file called `dot.profile` and put your environment variable.

As a general advice, when you face this kind of issue, use the `find` command to find which recipe provides which files

Comment: It took time to figure out exactly the  folder path and file names, but finally its working, also your find method is helping understand the path.

Comment: It's kind of bruteforce, but it always works. As a side note, I'd advise you to add:
# ROS autocompletion
source /opt/ros/indigo/share/rosbash/rosbash

#To use roswtf
export ROS_OS_OVERRIDE="ubuntu"

#Sets ROS_IP
export ROS_IP="$(ifconfig  | grep 'inet addr:'| grep -v '127.0.0.1' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}' | cut -d: -f1 | head -n 1 )"

#Adds autocompletion for ROS stuff
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/ros/indigo/bin

Comment: This doesn't work for me somehow. I created a .bbappend of the base-files recipe and put the file into ``files/dot.profile``, but nothing shows up in ``/etc/skel/.profile`` or ``/etc/profile``.

Comment: Is there more detail you can provide? I created a base-files_%.bbappend, however my dot.profile does not get applied (I still get the default). Do I need a higher layer priority or something? I'm using Petalinux, which also has a base-file_%.bbapppend (which does not modify dot.profile). Could that be the issue?

Comment: it's base-files, with an s. Make sure it is loaded, I can't remember the exact command but there is one to check which bbappends are used. other than that, I don't think petalinux would be an issue, but not sure

Comment: I did have the "s". I got it working by adding  "SRC_URI +=file://dot.profile" and a "do_install_append(){}" repeating the install command. Does that make sense or is it masking so other bug with my bbappend?

Comment: It's possible you got an other issue, e.g wrong path but I wouldn't worry about it...I didn't run yocto since warrior release so maybe there was some change...or it's petalinux doing this. Anyway, good you had it working 